# Parallel validation in Railway Oriented Programming C# while using FluentResults package

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I have a question about using Result class in ROP manner to implement parallel validations.

I am using FluentResults package:
https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults/blob/master/src/FluentResults/Results/Result.cs

Check this code as example:

```
public static Result<Email> Create(string email)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
        return Result.Fail<Email>("Email is empty");

    email = email.Trim();

    var validationResult = Result.Merge(
        Result.FailIf(email.Length > 200, "Email is bigger then 200 symbols"),
        Result.FailIf(!Regex.IsMatch(email, @"^(.+)@(.+)$"), $"'{email}' is not a valid email address")
    );

    if (validationResult.IsFailed)
        return validationResult;

    return Result.Ok(new Email(email));
}
```

This is an implementation of a factory method for Email ValueObject which is a common pattern for DDD.

Result.Merge allows me to do some checks in parallel and return an array of errors instead of failing on the first error. This is quite useful since we can send all found errors to the client. The downside of Result usage here is the code become very verbose and we have to check if Result fail on every level which is using this type.

On of suggested ways to reduce verbosity while using Result type is to follow Railway Oriented Programming (ROP) approach.
By writing a number of Generic extension method for Result class I was able to refactor this code to the following:

```
return email.ToResult("Email is empty")
    .OnSuccess(value => value.Trim())
    .Ensure(value => value.Length <= 200, "Email is bigger then 200 symbols")
    .Ensure(value => Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^(.+)@(.+)$"), $"'{email}' is not a valid email address")
    .Map(value => new Email(value));
```

This variant is less verbose. Though I have a problem here. The way how Ensure method is implemented rely on the fact that previous method in the chain succeeded. This mean we'll be able to catch only the first error in the chain. What I want to achieve is to keep parallel validation here after we checked that Email is not null or empty which can be achieved by .ToResult() call.

```
public static Result<T> Ensure<T>(this Result<T> result, Func<T, bool> predicate, string errorMessage)
{
    if (result.IsFailed)
        return result;

    if (!predicate(result.Value))
        return Result.Fail<T>(errorMessage);

    return result;
}
```

Can someone help me with some Validate extension method (or maybe some other which going to be more common for functional programming paradigm) which could take a params list of predicates with error messages, run the predicate and accumulate errors in case of failures. I want to achieve something like that:

```
public static Result<Email> Create(string email)
{
  return email.ToResult("Email is empty")
      .OnSuccess(value => value.Trim())
      .Validate(
        value => value.Length <= 200, "Email is bigger then 200 symbols"),
        value => Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^(.+)@(.+)$"), $"'{email}' is not a valid email address")
      )
      .Map(value => new Email(value));
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The standard way to achieve this is to use an sum type as an applicative functor. How is `Result` defined?

Comment: Here is Result definition: https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults/blob/master/src/FluentResults/Results/Result.cs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the *FluentResults* library, so I can't help with that. In general, a type like its `Result<T>` is so reminiscent of the more general `Result<TSuccess, TError>` that e.g. [F# defines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results). This is also known as `Either<L, R>` where `L` is for *left* and `R` is for *right*. Usually, you use *right for success*, since *right is right* (i.e. *correct*). Notice that used in this way, the rightmost type variable is used for success, which is opposite of *Result*, where the leftmost type variable is used to indicate success.

*Either* is both a [functor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/22/functors), an [applicative functor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/10/01/applicative-functors), and a monad. In order to enable the kind of 'parallel' error handling requested in the OP, you need the functionality of an applicative functor.

Unfortunately, C# doesn't have any good language features that support applicative functors - unlike [in F#](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/12/28/an-f-demo-of-validation-with-partial-data-round-trip) or [in Haskell](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/12/21/a-haskell-proof-of-concept-of-validation-with-partial-data-round-trip).

C# does, on the other hand, have decent support for monads. Since monads is a subset of applicative functors, it's easy to get the two confused and instead of leveraging a type's applicative features, you instead (inadvertently) use a type's monad features.

Particularly when it comes to validation, this is unfortunate, because the support for 'parallelisation' is exactly what distinguishes applicative functors from monads.

A function like the above `Ensure` exhibits the monadic behaviour of railway-oriented programming where, as soon as you've been shunted off to the error track, no further processing takes place.

[Applicative validation](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/11/05/applicative-validation), on the other hand, enables 'parallel validation' exactly by *not* being railway-oriented. Instead, it leverages the applicative nature of *Either*.

In order to compose *Either* values (or *Result* values) in parallel, in C#, you're either going to need a [set of `Apply` overloads](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/10/15/an-applicative-password-list/#9c3412586a58460c8280212a13351331), or alternatively, [as Tyson Williams points out](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/10/15/an-applicative-password-list/#0ded7ac93aad8ba7b1063dd49c2051f1), *currying*.

While a well-designed *Validation* type would be isomorphic to *Either*, it would have to be dedicated to support validation and only validation. As the [Haskell Validation library documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation/docs/Data-Validation.html) states:

> A consequence of this is that `Validation` has no `Bind` or `Monad` instance. This is because such an instance would violate the law that a `Monad`'s ap must equal the `Applicative`'s <*>.

In other words, in order to not be confusing, a *Validation* type would have to explicitly disallow monadic bind. In C#, this would mean that it explicitly must not come with any `SelectMany` method.

With an imperative design like *FluentResults*, however, this is hard to avoid because its various `Value` and `ValueOrDefault` members enable you to [get the value out of the monad](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/02/04/how-to-get-the-value-out-of-the-monad), so to speak. Thus, it's all too easy to inadvertently write functions that have monadic behaviour, like the above `Ensure` function.

Since I don't know the details of the *FluentResults* library, however, it may be that there's an API that does just what you need... If so, I'm sure someone else will come around and add that as an answer.